# Getting IllegalArgumentException:Unknown function while registering a function Apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to register a function as below:

```
String[] functionNames = { "removeExtraChar" } ;
    FreeRefFunction[] functionImpls = { new RemoveExtraChar() } ;
    UDFFinder udfToolpack = new DefaultUDFFinder( functionNames, functionImpls ) ;
    // register the user-defined function in the workbook
    workbook.addToolPack(udfToolpack);

    System.out.println("Registered function");

    Function func = new Function() {
        public ValueEval evaluate(ValueEval[] args, int srcRowIndex, int srcColumnIndex) {
            return ErrorEval.NA;
        }

    };

    WorkbookEvaluator.registerFunction("testRemoveExtraChar", func);
```

But I am getting IllegalargumentException as below:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown function: testRemoveExtraChar
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.FunctionEval.registerFunction(FunctionEval.java:354)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.registerFunction(WorkbookEvaluator.java:773)
```

Notice that the exception says "Unknown function". I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation at http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/user-defined-functions.html under "Registering Your Function", basically the following should suffice:

```
        String[] functionNames = { "calculatePayment" } ;
        FreeRefFunction[] functionImpls = { new CalculateMortgage() } ;

        UDFFinder udfToolpack = new DefaultUDFFinder( functionNames, functionImpls ) ;

        // register the user-defined function in the workbook
        workbook.addToolPack(udfToolpack);
```

So the registerFunction() should not be necessary any more.

See also the full example code at https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/formula/UserDefinedFunctionExample.java

`WorkbookEvaluator.registerFunction()` only allows to provide implementations of known functions, not userdefined ones.

Comment: we made the change suggested by you but "removeExtraChar" function is not available in the excel . Any clue why we are not able to see removeExtraChar in generated excel ?

Comment: I don't think the Excel file will "contain" the function afterwards. You implemented the function in Java, Excel only supports VBA. The intention here is to allow to re-implement your VBA function so POI can handle the file in a similar way as Excel.

Comment: @centic Is there any way to use a user-defined function that is already written in VBA from the excel file? (Since my VBA code is difficult to convert to Java code because it uses Chart object which is not completely implemented with Apache POI.)

Comment: There is currently no way to do this with Apache POI as it cannot interpret VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

As @centic pointed out in his comment , you should remove "WorkbookEvaluator.registerFunction()" And also the function registered using JAVA POI API will be **not** available to generated Excel .